# Is there a way I can use the FileReader method to read multiple text files?

Tags: java

Here is what I have so far.  It successfully reads chapter 1.txt and puts it into book.txt however, I need to have it accept 2 more chapters and this is where I am at a loss.  Is there a way I can use the FileReader method to read multiple text files?

`import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CatFiles
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
       File compiledChapters = new File("Book.txt");
       if(!compiledChapters.exists())
       {
           compiledChapters.createNewFile();
       } 
       FileReader myReader = new FileReader("chapter 1.txt");
       Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myReader);
       PrintWriter myWriter = new PrintWriter("Book.txt");
       while(myScanner.hasNextLine())
       {
           String textLine = myScanner.nextLine();
           myWriter.println(textLine);
       }

       myReader.close();
       myWriter.close();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way is to do this

```
FileReader myReader = new FileReader("chapter 1.txt");
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myReader);
PrintWriter myWriter = new PrintWriter("Book.txt");
while(myScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String textLine = myScanner.nextLine();
     myWriter.println(textLine);
}
myReader.close();

FileReader myReader2 = new FileReader("chapter 2.txt");
Scanner myScanner2 = new Scanner(myReader2);
while(myScanner2.hasNextLine())
{
    String textLine = myScanner.nextLine();
     myWriter.println(textLine);
}
myReader2.close();

FileReader myReader3 = new FileReader("chapter 3.txt");
Scanner myScanner3 = new Scanner(myReader3);
while(myScanner3.hasNextLine())
{
    String textLine = myScanner.nextLine();
     myWriter.println(textLine);
}
myReader3.close();

myWriter.close();
```

But this is very ugly and probably need to be in a method of it's own like

```
WriteChapter("Chapter 1.txt");
WriteChapter("Chapter 2.txt");
WriteChapter("Chapter 3.txt");
```